# wp_localize_script escaping my url - fix or alternative

Tags: ajax, api

Here is my wp_enqueue_script and wp_localize_script - which i am using to run an Ajax call.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'function', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'function.js', array( 'jquery', 'json2' ) );
wp_localize_script( 'function', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

While debugging this problem arose:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
    var MyAjax = {"ajaxurl":"http:\/\/mydomain.com\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php"};
    /* ]]> */
    </script>
```

As you can see my url is been escaped out and i have no idea why... is there a possible fix or alternative method for what i am trying to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your end goal? If you use that in your ajax calls it will work just fine.

Comment: @Danny, if it's fixed, please post what you did to fix it as an Answer so future visitors to the site can benefit.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't "fixed" as such, i just realised that escaped or not it still functions correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wp_localize_script()` now uses `json_encode()` which means a multidimensional array will now work for the passed data. And, HTML entity decoding only applies to the first level of the array.

Better is an way to use json and default js possibilities from WP.

At first, i add the options from the database via script and `json_encode` to wp header:

```
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'fb_print_scripts' );

    function fb_print_scripts() {
        global $current_screen;

        if ( isset( $current_screen -> id ) && ! in_array( $current_screen -> id, array( 'post', 'page' ) ) )
            return;

        if ( is_plugin_active_for_network( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
            $options = get_site_option( 'my_options_id' );
        else
            $options = get_option( 'my_options_id' );

        if ( ! $options )
            return;
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var my_json_object = <?php echo htmlspecialchars( json_encode( $options ) ); ?>;
        </script>
        <?php
    }
```

after this i read this data via javascript; the script include via `wp_enqueue_script`; the follow example init only in admin, you can change the hook without `admin_` to include also in frontend.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'fb_admin_enqueue_scripts' );

function fb_admin_enqueue_scripts( $where ) {

    if ( ! in_array( $where, array( 'post.php', 'post-new.php', ) )
        return;

    $suffix = defined('SCRIPT_DEBUG') && SCRIPT_DEBUG ? '.dev' : '';

    wp_enqueue_script(
        self :: get_textdomain() . '_script',
        plugins_url( '/js/my_script' . $suffix. '.js', __FILE__ ),
        array( 'jquery', 'my_other_script' ),
        '',
        TRUE
    );

}
```

now you can use the data from json inside your script, example

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    if ( typeof my_json_object == 'undefined' )
        return;

// debug in console of Browser
console.dir( my_json_object ); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from when you are firing the wp_localize_script call. Most likely you are just writing that code into your plugin which loads far too early.

I struggled with the problem for a while as well. If you wrap the code in a function and use add_action on wp_head it works as expected.

```
function ajaxurl() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-request', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/ajax.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array(
// URL to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php to process the request
'ajaxurl'          => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),

// generate a nonce with a unique ID "myajax-post-comment-nonce"
// so that you can check it later when an AJAX request is sent
'postCommentNonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'myajax-post-comment-nonce' ),
)
);


}
add_action('wp_head', 'ajaxurl');
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `wp_head`, but `wp_enqueue_scripts` for scripts, styles that are loading on public facing pages.